# How to get all taxonomies which can be added in menu?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus, taxonomy

I am trying to get list of available taxonomies which WordPress admin users can use in menu section, like `Categories`, `Tags`, `Product Categories`, `Product Tags` or any custom taxonomy for custom post type.
Using `get_taxonomies` results all taxonomies, some of which are not available in Menu screen, for example Product shipping Class (from woocommerce).

In short, I am trying to get all those taxonomies which are used with `Post`, `Page`, `Products` or any other `Custom Post Type` in right side of editing screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The taxonomies visible in the admin menu are exactly those taxonomies that were registered with `show_in_menu = true` and `show_ui = true`. For a reference on this, see the documentation on [`register_taxonomy`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy), the function for adding (custom) taxonomies.

To query these taxonomies, use the corresponding parameters in [`get_taxonomies`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies):

```
get_taxonomies( array(
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
) );
```

Comment: Thank you very much @engelen ! It works. Reason I miss it becasue I can not see it in documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies) and [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_taxonomies)
Also after seeing your code, I saw many other parameters.
Once again thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome, @sanjayojha!